# Checking date format in Karma Jasmine unit test case

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, date, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm having a logic that converts date to new Date()

```
$scope.isValidatStartDate=function("2016-05-04")
{
   var dateList = date.split("-");
   $scope.endMaxDate = new Date(dateList[0], dateList[1] - 1, dateList[2]);
}
```

I have written test case to check whether the passed date is in the format of new Date();

```
  it("Expect date should be validated", function () {
            var date = "2016-05-04";
            scope.isValidatStartDate(date);
            expect(scope.endMaxDate).toBe("Wed May 04 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)");
        });
```

But the test is failing as the message in the **Karma debugger console** says..

> debug.html:38 Expected Date(Wed May 04 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India
>   Standard Time)) to be 'Wed May 04 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India
>   Standard Time)'.

The test expects Date object to be string.Hence it is failing.How can I check instead of string if the date object is really a date object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please compare again a Date:

```
var date = new Date("Wed May 04 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)")
expect(scope.endMaxDate).toBe(date)
```

also check you code:

```
$scope..endMaxDate
```

You have two points